# How to use articles

Tags: grammar, articles

which one of the following sentences is correct and why, thanks in advance

1. I would like chicken
2. I would like ***a*** chicken
3. I would like ***some*** chicken

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All three are correct, but sentence 2 is arguably different in meaning.

We need to distinguish between the **bird** and the **meat from that bird**. "Chicken" can refer to both (see [definitions 1 and 2 at OALD](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/chicken_1)). With some animals in English, we have different words for their respective meats (pig and pork, cow and beef), but not so with chicken.

Sentence 1 and 3 both imply that the speaker would like an unspecified amount of meat from a chicken. But because chicken as food is uncountable (see def. 2 at OALD), the indefinite article in sentence 2 implies that the speaker would like an entire (presumably living) chicken (def. 1 at OALD), possibly to keep as a pet.

If you want to imply that you would like the entire carcass of a chicken for cooking or consumption, you could instead of sentence 2 specify that you would like a *whole* chicken.

Comment: I will only add that you can ask for "a chicken" to eat if you mean that you intend to eat a whole chicken.  (Normally a Cornish game hen or other small one.)